# Rayleigh scattering, what's it's equation and why?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have looked at rayleigh scattering on Wikipedia and it listed the equation

[image]

[source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/b/e/8/be8d955b92a1ebd2f85c111819788c2e.png)

However it did not give thorough explanation to what are the angle θ and distance R, nor how they influence the intensity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering Here is the link.

Comment: From the link you provided: "R is the distance to the particle and θ is the scattering angle."

Answer (score 2):

$R$ is the distance from the particle to the point where you observe the scattered intensity; $\theta$ is the angle between the incident and the scattered ray (so $\theta=0$ is no scatter, and $\theta=180°$ is complete backscatter.

You can see the intensity follows the inverse square law (consider the particle a "point source" of scattered radiation) and that there is a dependence on both the particle size ($d^6$) and the angle. There is also a strong ($\frac{1}{\lambda^4}$) dependence on wavelength - the reason the sky is blue (blue light, shorter wavelength, more strongly scattered).